# Google Drive SDK File.List properties

Tags: google-drive-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I'm using v2 of the Google Drive SDK for C#.

I get a FilesResource.List request from the Files.List().Execute().

The actual REST API shows the "properties" field should be included with this response; however, I cannot find any properties field on each item in enumerable collection of request.Items[x] in Drive.v2.Data.File.cs.

How can I get the properties from the initial request?

Answer (score 1):

By calling Files.List().Execute() you are getting back a list of Files.

File contains several properties including "AlternateLink", "DownloadUrl", "Properties" and others. Your ListRequest object (which is returned from Files.List()) contains all the different properties you can set.

Please attach code to make your question more clear.

Answer (score 0):

My goof I overlooked the field.

Get a file via list or creation

Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.File newFile = new Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.File();

Then

List lstMetadata = (newFile.Properties == null) ? new List() : newFile.Properties.ToList();